# Does the "sin that dwelleth in me" corresponds to kundalini?

Tags: sin, kundalini

In the Letter to the Romans, the apostle Paul writes about "sin" as some entity that dwells in the human body.

Now, I do believe that this entity corresponds to kundalini.

> sin entered into the world (5,12)

The apostle writes about sin not just as an act performed by human beings, but also as some entity that came into the world from outside.

I have read that kundalini dwells dormant at the bottom of the spine until it is stimulated. It then raises through the spine and reaches the brain. Kundalini is a dualistic primordial force. When it raises through the two side channels ida and pingala, it strikes the two cerebral hemispheres producing in the mind a dualistic attitude so that the mind pursuits things to be "liked" and things to be "disliked" - in other words it produces in the mind an illusory pursuit of "good" and "evil". This spoiled state of mind pushes the person to seek material pleasures and, at the same time, to innaturally avoid other things.

> Now then it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me. (7,17)

> Let not sin therefore reign in your mortal body, that ye should obey it in the lusts thereof. Neither yield ye your members as instruments of unrighteousness unto sin (6,12-13)

> So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin. (7,25)

In this verses it seems that the apostle is speaking exactly of this primordial force, kundalini. He recognizes that there is something in his body that pushes him to do things he doesn't want to do. The force Paul is writing about is evidently strong and primordial, connected with lust and libido.

> What shall we say then? Is the law sin? God forbid. Nay, I had not known sin, but by the law: for I had not known lust, except the law had said, Thou shalt not covet. But sin, taking occasion by the commandment, wrought in me all manner of concupiscence. For without the law sin was dead. For I was alive without the law once: but when the commandment came, sin revived, and I died. (7,7-9)

> For sin, taking occasion by the commandment, deceived me, and by it slew me. (7,11)

> For when the Gentiles, which have not the law, do by nature the things contained in the law, these, having not the law, are a law unto themselves (2,14)

Paul writes here about the jewish law. That law is nothing more than a collection of written rules to follow not to incur sin. These rules are also written in the heart of people, but it seems that the jews need them to be written on paper... When a jew reads the law, sin takes occasion of the law to deceive and slew him. How does this happen? When the jew reads the law, he deludes himself to know that law. He produces in his mind the illusion to know the law - to know what is good and what is evil. And it is there that sin, the primordial force, acts in his mind, pushing it to pursue material pleasures. This is exactly how kundalini works in the mind.

> Being then made free from sin, ye became the servants of righteousness. (6,18)

> But now being made free from sin, and become servants to God, ye have your fruit unto holiness, and the end everlasting life. (6,22)

Here the apostle writes about becoming free of sin. This happens when someone frees himself from the dualistic oppression operated by kundalini in his mind, which pushed him to pursue obsessively material pleasures. After that, the person may perform spiritual progress, and when the time is ripe he will be able to tame the kundalini, making it raise through the central channel, sushumna.

Comment: Kundalini is not sin, she is Supreme Goddess.. She exists in form like Para Kundalini (Supreme Energy), Chit Kundalini (Power of Consciousness) and Prana Kundalini (Power of Prana)... generally people only refer to Prana Kundalini while talking about Kundalini...!

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I am going to remove the post from here and will write it in the philosophy forum

Answer (score 1):

No, Kundalini is not the same as sin. Kundalini is Sakti and is one with Pure Consciousness. In theology Kundalini Sakti is the Divine Mother. It is She who evolves mind, senses and five Bhutas (sensible matter). After She evolves solid matter (earth), Her creative activity stops and she coils round the Svayambhu-Linga in Muladhara chakra and 'sleeps'.

> The ultimate or irreducible reality is 'Spirit' in the sense of Pure
> Consciousness (cit) from out of which as and by its Power (Sakti),
> mind and matter proceed. Spirit is one. There are no degrees or
> differences in Spirit. The Spirit which is in man is the one Spirit
> which is in everything and which, as the object of worship, is the
> Lord (Isvara) or God. Mind and matter are many and of many degrees and
> qualities. Atma or Spirit as such is the Whole (Purna) without section
> (Akhanda). Mind and matter are parts in that Whole. They are the
> not-whole (Apurna) and are the section (Khanda). Spirit is infinite
> (Aparicchinna) and formless (Arupa). Mind and matter are finite
> (Parichinna) and with form (Rupa). Atma is unchanged and inactive. Its
> Power (Sakti) is active and changes in the form of Mind and Matter.
> Pure Consciousness is Cit or Samvit. Matter as such is the
> unconscious. And Mind too is unconscious according to Vedanta. For
> all that is not the conscious self is the unconscious object. This
> does not mean that it is unconsciousness in itself. On the contrary
> all is essentially consciousness, but that it is unconscious because
> it is the object of the conscious self. For mind limits Consciousness
> so as to enable man to have finite experience. There is no mind
> without consciousness as its background, though supreme Consciousness
> is Mindless (Amanah). Where there is no mind (Amanah) there is no
> limitation. Consciousness remaining in one aspect unchanged changes in
> its other aspect as active Power which manifests as Mind and Body. Man
> then is Pure Consciousness (Cit) vehicled by its Power as Mind and
> Body.
>
> In theology this Pure Consciousness is Siva, and His Power (Sakti) who
> as She is in Her formless self is one with Him. **She is the great Devi,
> the Mother of the Universe who as the Life-force resides in man's body
> in its lowest centre at the base of the spine** just as Siva is realized
> in the highest brain centre, the cerebrum or Sahasrara-Padma.
> Completed Yoga is the Union of Her and Him in the body of the Sadhaka.
> This is Laya or dissolution, the reverse of Spirit in Mind and Matter.

**The Serpent Power, Chapter II, Bodiless Consciousness, by Sir John Woodruffe**